# Temp gauge falsely overheating

Tags: ford, overheating, explorer

We had an issue with an coolant leak and we were able to find the problem and fix it. About a month or two later we noticed our 2006 Ford Explorer with a V8 was saying it was overheating but when we check the temperature of the engine, it is not actually overheating. Its not losing fluid, it's not over overfilling, We have replaced the thermostat, radiator, cylinder head temperature sensor, we have checked the fan and replace the water pump. They did an exhaust test  and also the coolant is clean and there's  nothing floating in it  in the radiator .. radiator cap was also replaced. The Ford dealership flashed the computer, we also made sure to get the air out of the coolant and radiator, we burped the explorer, and it's spent about 4 days at the dealership and they couldn't figure out why it was saying it's overheating when it really wasn't. They want to charge us $500 to dig into the engine more because at one point they said the cylinder head isn't getting coolant. Which we didn't believe them because we would have other problems if that was the case and it would probably actually overheating or leaking. At this point we think it must be the electrical harness or could be the computer??? The Ford dealership did say that something was going online and offline quite a bit? Help! We are banging our heads on the wall!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if the coolant system was purged of all air? If steam pockets (from the air) get to where the sensor is located, it will show as high on your gauge (steam is hotter than liquid).

Comment: The one time I had this happen to me, the cause was simply a damaged lead to the temperature sensor (i.e. the lead itself was damaged part way along its length, the connectors at each end were perfectly OK.) Sometimes, it's the little things that get you ;)

Comment: Was Stop Leak or a similar product ever used in the car when it had a coolant leak? That could have clogged up and still be in there.  That crap is a temporary solution and a headache for the life of the engine.